# Determine the arc rotation direction (circular)?

Tags: geometry, circles

This has done doing my head in for the past few days. I'm working with a CAD software that gives me the following information about arc:

```
[Axis.X,Axis.Y,Axis.Z,Center.X,Center.Y,Center.Z,Radius]
```

and

```
[StartPoint.X,StartPoint.Y,StartPoint.Z,EndPoint.X,EndPoint.Y,EndPoint.Z]
```

The docs are pretty much dry on what the Axis means? My guess would be is the axis of rotation from Start to End. I'm not sure either.

How would I determine the rotation direction (clockwise or counter) giving the information above. I've tried several approaches not to avail.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to provide the name of the software, if someone also uses it he could give a direct answer. Also, I guess this is 2D? When you say arc, is it only circular arc or does that include elliptic arc? Intuitively, the meaning of these parameters eludes me, but by default I'd say the rotation is always in the counter-clockwise direction. Do you want the direction or the angle by the way?

Comment: The software is SOLIDWORKS. I know its API pretty well, and I can't find any good information. This is 2D, yes. Yes, only circular arcs. I simply want to know is the direction (clock wise or counter) that the software used to draw the arc so I can redraw in WPF.

Comment: @N.Bach I want the direction. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, if you want to redraw, shouldn't it be easy to test both directions on a simple example? Also, if these parameters are only the "display/drawing" parameters, then they seem a bit redundant. I assume this has to do with the internal working of the software, but strictly speaking in 2D, "axis of rotation" as you described it, and "center" are the same. They are different when you switch to 3D though. It should be possible to encode different rotation direction depending on the direction of the "axis", but in 2D you'd usually use the "Z coordinate" for that, so this seems weird.

Comment: Having a concrete example seems to be the easiest way.

Comment: @N.Bach: Actually, the data has a z coordinates. So what are you saying is true? How would I approach it.

Comment: I believe it is the counter clockwise direction according to the axis, see @amd 's answer. In the simpler 2D case, that is if everything is in the plane $Z=0$, the axis.X/Y should be $0$, but axis.Z should be non-zero. If my guess is true, axis.Z > 0 means counter-clockwise, axis.Z < 0 is clockwise.

Comment: @N.Bach I think you need to look at the direction of the `AXIS` vector as a whole. The `AXIS.Z` value isn’t going to tell you anything about the rotation direction when the plane is vertical, for instance. My guess based on no information is that the direction in which the arc is traced is determined by the right-hand rule relative to the `AXIS` vector.

Comment: @amd: I'm going to use the normal surface of the arc plane to determine if the arc's axis and the surface is normal are pointing in the same direction.

Comment: @amd Well, that's basically what I wanted to say. The right-hand rule means that when you look at the plane defined by the axis and center from "above", you should rotate in the counter-clockwise direction. Since my description was lackluster, I just gave the example in the 2D case, since at first it was phrased as a 2D problem (assuming solidworks use right-handed coordinates systems).

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that `Axis` is a normal to the plane in which the arc lies, i.e., the plane given by the point-normal equation $\text{Axis}\cdot(x,y,z)=\text{Axis}\cdot\text{Center}$.

“Direction of rotation” is a somewhat slippery concept once you move beyond 2-D, one that literally depends on how you look at it: A planar circular arc that appears to be traced clockwise when viewed from one side of the plane will appear to be traced counterclockwise from the other side. No doubt the `Axis` parameter is also used to define an orientation—the “positive” direction of rotation, but you’ll either have to experiment or look up the documentation for your software to see how it’s used.

Comment: I'll try that and check your answers if it's correct

Comment: This doesn't work :(

Comment: @Jelly Simply stating that without showing your work providing any data isn’t going to help anyone figure out what’s going on. As N.Back said in his comment, provide a concrete example.

Comment: I'll. I was a bit frustrated though